# Get the same output of Netcat in Java

Tags: java, sockets, port, serversocket, netcat

I want to get the same output (in Java) that I get when I do this in the terminal (with Netcat):

```
nc -l localhost 8080
```

The output I get is:

```
GET /?code=Mdf81e469-fca0-f04e-db95-278aff0323be HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de-de
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/601.4.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.3 Safari/601.4.4
```

I need this because of the output in the first line after the `GET`. I want to have it as a `String`value in Java.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Runtime` class's `exec` method to execute this command and get back the result. Here is a small example that you can modify as per your requirement:

```
  String[] commands = new String[]{"nc", "localhost", "8080"};
  Process childProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
  InputStream in = childProc.getInputStream();
  int c;
  while ((c = in.read()) != -1) 
  {
    System.out.print((char)c);
  }
  in.close();
```

Hope this helps!